# Append in Python adds extra unexpected element to list in between computed values

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I am generating some numbers and each time I generate one I want to store it in a list.

The code:

```
for m in plaintexts:
    H = V = []

    for k in xrange(0, 256):
        di = m[i_temp1 : i_temp2]
        entry = int(sBox[int(di, 16) ^ k])
        print entry
        V.append(entry)
        print V
        H.append(bin(entry).count("1"))
    tempV.append(V)
    tempH.append(H)
```

What I get is unfortunately quite different:

```
89
[89]
250
[89, 4, 250]
240
[89, 4, 250, 6, 240]
71
[89, 4, 250, 6, 240, 4, 71]
130
[89, 4, 250, 6, 240, 4, 71, 4, 130]
202
[89, 4, 250, 6, 240, 4, 71, 4, 130, 2, 202]
125
[89, 4, 250, 6, 240, 4, 71, 4, 130, 2, 202, 4, 125]
```

The values I calculate are being added, but a random number is always added between each computed value, these random values are always between 2-8.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`H` and `V` are the *same list*. Create separate lists for each:

```
H, V = [], []
```

The line `H = V = []` creates only *one* list, then assigns it to both `H` and `V`:

```
>>> H = V = []
>>> H is V
True
>>> H.append(42)
>>> V
[42]
>>> H, V = [], []
>>> H is V
False
>>> H.append(42)
>>> V
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=b=[]
>>> a.append('hello b')
>>> a,b
(['hello b'], ['hello b'])
>>> a,b=[],[]
>>> a.append('sorry b')
>>> a,b
(['sorry b'], [])
```